# How do I index a list contained inside *args?

Tags: python

having trouble getting a single value from the list in the 'funCall' function. Any idea how to index the *args?

```
def funCall(*args):
    ans = args[0]
    print(ans)

def roll(a_list):
    check = []
    for i in a_list:
        if a_list.count(i) > 2:
            check.append(i)
    print(check)
    if len(check) == 3:
        funCall(check)


roll([3, 2, 3, 5, 3])
```

Comment: Why are you using `*args` in the first place?

Comment: `args` is a tuple. What's the trouble here?

Comment: If my answer below answered your question, please accept it. If not please add a comment of what still confuses you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood how `*args` works. Args is a tuple and contain all not-named arguments passed in to the method.

For example imagine this:

```
def foo(*args):
    print(args)

foo([1,2,3], True, 1) # Prints ([1,2,3], True, 1,)
foo(*[1,2,3]) # Prints (1,2,3,)
```

Args is a tuple that contains all of the argument passed in. So in your case `args[0]` is just the first thing passed in, not the first index of your list.

If you want to populate the tuple with your item values you can pass it in prefixed with a `*` like this `foo(*[1, 2, 3,])`. That will print out `(1, 2, 3,)` and your index 0 will be the first item of the list you passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `check` to `funCall` like so:

```
if len(check) == 3:
    funCall(*check)
```

Now, in `funCall`, `ans` will be storing the first element in `check`